# keeping view name and corresponding controller method name different

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have a controller method named `CreatePANApplication` but I have created view page for this named as `PANApplication`. Now when I am trying to call this method from another view page as:

```
// dataTable code block
<td>    
    @Html.ActionLink("PAN Application", "CreatePANApplication", new { id = item.PANKey }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
</td>
```

getting error as:

```
The view 'CreatePANApplication' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.
```

*It means that I should not keep my controller name and corresponding view page name different.* But many times we have to change the view page name, what can we do at that time?

Controller class:

```
public ActionResult CreatePANApplication(int? id)
        {
            try
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
                var data = (from z in db.PANModels
                            where z.PANKey == id
                            select z).ToList();

                if (data == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View(data);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does the controller look like?

Comment: @AliK I have added the controller method.

Comment: Right now your controller will expect view called CreatePANApplication.cshtml.  You can call the view whatever you want like pagepan.cshtml and call is as return View("pagename",data)

Comment: what you are returning from CreatePANApplication action method and do you have the CreatePANApplication.cshtml file in the same directory as controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your view is still in the  folder that is named as a controller, or you put your view in a Shared folder, you can use this

```
 return View("PANApplication", data);
```

but if your view is in different folder you will have to use the full path

```
return View(" ~/Views/folder/PANApplication.cshtml", data);
```